# How to avoid positioning ChartJS's tooltip on specific datasets on a chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) to display stripes (ranges) and inside each stripe I'm display a line of the median value. I'm hiding the stripes' presence in both the legend and tooltip lists. That's done by adding this string in the dataset label: "HIDE!" and then just filtering out those items through the tooltip and legend options.

When I move the mouse over the chart, I've configured the tooltip to be  positioned on the nearest vector, but that should only be hapenning on the line datasets, and **not** on the stripe datasets. Examples below:

**Tooltip using a stripe as nearest vector (this is NOT ok):**

[image: problem]

**Tooltip using a line as nearest vector (this is ok):**

[image: tooltip on point]

So the question is: How can I avoid positioning the tooltip tick on the stripes' vectors, and only use the lines' vectors for that? It seems that the filter option only hides the item from the legend list itself, but not from the graphic when it comes to position the tooltip div.

Here's my current code (you can check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp4c39fe/) as well):

```
<canvas id="rainbow"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
var chart;
var aspectRatio = 2;
if(window.innerWidth < 600) {
    aspectRatio = 1;
}
var chartdata = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        //months
        labels: ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60"],
        datasets : [

            //##################################################

            {
                //tracking (white dotted line)
                type: 'line',
                data: [50.9,54.6,,62,,,68.3,68.9,70.5,73,74.4,,,77.5,79.7,,,82.4,,,85.7,,,88.9,90.6,90.1,,92,93,,,95.6,96.4,,99.1,98.9,,,,,,103.4,104.2,,,,,108.7,,,110.7,111.3,,111.6,,,113.5,114.1,115.7,116.3,],
                label: "name",
                borderColor: "#ffffff",
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 1,
                borderWidth: 3,
                spanGaps: true,
                borderDash: [10,5]
            },

            //##################################################

            {
                //3 SD line [7]
                data: [54.7,59.5,63.2,66.1,68.6,70.7,72.5,74.2,75.8,77.4,78.9,80.3,81.7,83.1,84.4,85.7,87.0,88.2,89.4,90.6,91.7,92.9,94.0,95.0,95.8,96.4,97.4,98.4,99.4,100.3,101.3,102.2,103.1,103.9,104.8,105.6,106.5,107.3,108.1,108.9,109.7,110.5,111.2,112.0,112.7,113.5,114.2,114.9,115.7,116.4,117.1,117.7,118.4,119.1,119.8,120.4,121.1,121.8,122.4,123.1,123.7],
                label: "3 SD",
                backgroundColor: "#8ac4e8",
                borderColor: "#8ac4e8",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
                //2 SD line [6]
                data: [52.9,57.6,61.1,64.0,66.4,68.5,70.3,71.9,73.5,75.0,76.4,77.8,79.2,80.5,81.7,83.0,84.2,85.4,86.5,87.6,88.7,89.8,90.8,91.9,92.6,93.1,94.1,95.0,96.0,96.9,97.7,98.6,99.4,100.3,101.1,101.9,102.7,103.4,104.2,105.0,105.7,106.4,107.2,107.9,108.6,109.3,110.0,110.7,111.3,112.0,112.7,113.3,114.0,114.6,115.2,115.9,116.5,117.1,117.7,118.3,118.9],
                label: "2 SD",
                backgroundColor: "#80a3e6",
                borderColor: "#80a3e6",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
                //1 SD line [5]
                data: [51.0,55.6,59.1,61.9,64.3,66.2,68.0,69.6,71.1,72.6,73.9,75.3,76.6,77.8,79.1,80.2,81.4,82.5,83.6,84.7,85.7,86.7,87.7,88.7,89.3,89.9,90.8,91.7,92.5,93.4,94.2,95.0,95.8,96.6,97.4,98.1,98.9,99.6,100.3,101.0,101.7,102.4,103.1,103.8,104.5,105.1,105.8,106.4,107.0,107.7,108.3,108.9,109.5,110.1,110.7,111.3,111.9,112.5,113.0,113.6,114.2],
                label: "1 SD",
                backgroundColor: "#7780e4",
                borderColor: "#7780e4",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
                //Median [4]
                data: [49.1,53.7,57.1,59.8,62.1,64.0,65.7,67.3,68.7,70.1,71.5,72.8,74.0,75.2,76.4,77.5,78.6,79.7,80.7,81.7,82.7,83.7,84.6,85.5,86.1,86.6,87.4,88.3,89.1,89.9,90.7,91.4,92.2,92.9,93.6,94.4,95.1,95.7,96.4,97.1,97.7,98.4,99.0,99.7,100.3,100.9,101.5,102.1,102.7,103.3,103.9,104.5,105.0,105.6,106.2,106.7,107.3,107.8,108.4,108.9,109.4],
                label: "Median",
                backgroundColor: "#8c77e4",
                borderColor: "#8c77e4",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
                //-1 SD line [3]
                data: [47.3,51.7,55.0,57.7,59.9,61.8,63.5,65.0,66.4,67.7,69.0,70.3,71.4,72.6,73.7,74.8,75.8,76.8,77.8,78.8,79.7,80.6,81.5,82.3,82.9,83.3,84.1,84.9,85.7,86.4,87.1,87.9,88.6,89.3,89.9,90.6,91.2,91.9,92.5,93.1,93.8,94.4,95.0,95.6,96.2,96.7,97.3,97.9,98.4,99.0,99.5,100.1,100.6,101.1,101.6,102.2,102.7,103.2,103.7,104.2,104.7],
                label: "-1 SD",
                backgroundColor: "#aa78e5",
                borderColor: "#aa78e5",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
                //-2 SD line [2]
                data: [45.4,49.8,53.0,55.6,57.8,59.6,61.2,62.7,64.0,65.3,66.5,67.7,68.9,70.0,71.0,72.0,73.0,74.0,74.9,75.8,76.7,77.5,78.4,79.2,79.7,80.0,80.8,81.5,82.2,82.9,83.6,84.3,84.9,85.6,86.2,86.8,87.4,88.0,88.6,89.2,89.8,90.4,90.9,91.5,92.0,92.5,93.1,93.6,94.1,94.6,95.1,95.6,96.1,96.6,97.1,97.6,98.1,98.5,99.0,99.5,99.9],
                label: "-2 SD",
                backgroundColor: "#c97be5",
                borderColor: "#c97be5",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            {
                //-3 SD line [1]
                data: [43.6,47.8,51.0,53.5,55.6,57.4,58.9,60.3,61.7,62.9,64.1,65.2,66.3,67.3,68.3,69.3,70.2,71.1,72.0,72.8,73.7,74.5,75.2,76.0,76.4,76.8,77.5,78.1,78.8,79.5,80.1,80.7,81.3,81.9,82.5,83.1,83.6,84.2,84.7,85.3,85.8,86.3,86.8,87.4,87.9,88.4,88.9,89.3,89.8,90.3,90.7,91.2,91.7,92.1,92.6,93.0,93.4,93.9,94.3,94.7,95.2],
                label: "-3 SD",
                backgroundColor: "#dc7db7",
                borderColor: "#dc7db7",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 2
            },

            //##################################################

            {
                //3 SD stripe [7]
                data: [55.6,60.45,64.25,67.15,69.7,71.8,73.6,75.35,76.95,78.6,80.15,81.55,82.95,84.4,85.75,87.05,88.4,89.6,90.85,92.1,93.2,94.45,95.6,96.55,97.4,98.05,99.05,100.1,101.1,102,103.1,104,104.95,105.7,106.65,107.45,108.4,109.25,110.05,110.85,111.7,112.55,113.2,114.05,114.75,115.6,116.3,117,117.9,118.6,119.3,119.9,120.6,121.35,122.1,122.65,123.4,124.15,124.75,125.5,126.1],
                label: "HIDE!3 SD",
                borderColor: "#7bb5d9",
                backgroundColor: "#7bb5d9",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 9
            },
            {
                //2 SD stripe [6]
                data: [53.8,58.55,62.15,65.05,67.5,69.6,71.4,73.05,74.65,76.2,77.65,79.05,80.45,81.8,83.05,84.35,85.6,86.8,87.95,89.1,90.2,91.35,92.4,93.45,94.2,94.75,95.75,96.7,97.7,98.6,99.5,100.4,101.25,102.1,102.95,103.75,104.6,105.35,106.15,106.95,107.7,108.45,109.2,109.95,110.65,111.4,112.1,112.8,113.5,114.2,114.9,115.5,116.2,116.85,117.5,118.15,118.8,119.45,120.05,120.7,121.3],
                label: "HIDE!2 SD",
                borderColor: "#7194d7",
                backgroundColor: "#7194d7",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 10
            },
            {
                //1 SD stripe [5]
                data: [51.95,56.6,60.1,62.95,65.35,67.35,69.15,70.75,72.3,73.8,75.15,76.55,77.9,79.15,80.4,81.6,82.8,83.95,85.05,86.15,87.2,88.25,89.25,90.3,90.95,91.5,92.45,93.35,94.25,95.15,95.95,96.8,97.6,98.45,99.25,100,100.8,101.5,102.25,103,103.7,104.4,105.15,105.85,106.55,107.2,107.9,108.55,109.15,109.85,110.5,111.1,111.75,112.35,112.95,113.6,114.2,114.8,115.35,115.95,116.55],
                label: "HIDE!1 SD",
                borderColor: "#6871d5",
                backgroundColor: "#6871d5",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 11
            },

            //##################################################

            {
                //Median stripe [4]
                data: [50.05,54.65,58.1,60.85,63.2,65.1,66.85,68.45,69.9,71.35,72.7,74.05,75.3,76.5,77.75,78.85,80,81.1,82.15,83.2,84.2,85.2,86.15,87.1,87.7,88.25,89.1,90,90.8,91.65,92.45,93.2,94,94.75,95.5,96.25,97,97.65,98.35,99.05,99.7,100.4,101.05,101.75,102.4,103,103.65,104.25,104.85,105.5,106.1,106.7,107.25,107.85,108.45,109,109.6,110.15,110.7,111.25,111.8],
                label: "HIDE!Median",
                borderColor: "#7d68d5",
                backgroundColor: "#7d68d5",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 12
            },

            //##################################################

            {
                //-1 SD stripe [3]
                data: [48.2,52.7,56.05,58.75,61,62.9,64.6,66.15,67.55,68.9,70.25,71.55,72.7,73.9,75.05,76.15,77.2,78.25,79.25,80.25,81.2,82.15,83.05,83.9,84.5,84.95,85.75,86.6,87.4,88.15,88.9,89.65,90.4,91.1,91.75,92.5,93.15,93.8,94.45,95.1,95.75,96.4,97,97.65,98.25,98.8,99.4,100,100.55,101.15,101.7,102.3,102.8,103.35,103.9,104.45,105,105.5,106.05,106.55,107.05],
                label: "HIDE!-1 SD",
                borderColor: "#9b69d6",
                backgroundColor: "#9b69d6",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 13
            },
            {
                //-2 SD stripe [2]
                data: [46.35,50.75,54,56.65,58.85,60.7,62.35,63.85,65.2,66.5,67.75,69,70.15,71.3,72.35,73.4,74.4,75.4,76.35,77.3,78.2,79.05,79.95,80.75,81.3,81.65,82.45,83.2,83.95,84.65,85.35,86.1,86.75,87.45,88.05,88.7,89.3,89.95,90.55,91.15,91.8,92.4,92.95,93.55,94.1,94.6,95.2,95.75,96.25,96.8,97.3,97.85,98.35,98.85,99.35,99.9,100.4,100.85,101.35,101.85,102.3],
                label: "HIDE!-2 SD",
                borderColor: "#ba6cd6",
                backgroundColor: "#ba6cd6",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 14
            },
            {
                //-3 SD stripe [1]
                data: [44.5,48.8,52,54.55,56.7,58.5,60.05,61.5,62.85,64.1,65.3,66.45,67.6,68.65,69.65,70.65,71.6,72.55,73.45,74.3,75.2,76,76.8,77.6,78.05,78.4,79.15,79.8,80.5,81.2,81.85,82.5,83.1,83.75,84.35,84.95,85.5,86.1,86.65,87.25,87.8,88.35,88.85,89.45,89.95,90.45,91,91.45,91.95,92.45,92.9,93.4,93.9,94.35,94.85,95.3,95.75,96.2,96.65,97.1,97.55],
                label: "HIDE!-3 SD",
                borderColor: "#cd6ea8",
                backgroundColor: "#cd6ea8",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 0,
                pointHoverRadius: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: 15
            },

            //##################################################

            {
                //artificial base
                data: [42.7,46.8,50,52.45,54.5,56.3,57.75,59.1,60.55,61.7,62.9,63.95,65,65.95,66.95,67.95,68.8,69.65,70.55,71.3,72.2,73,73.6,74.4,74.75,75.2,75.85,76.4,77.1,77.8,78.35,78.9,79.5,80.05,80.65,81.25,81.7,82.3,82.75,83.35,83.8,84.25,84.75,85.35,85.85,86.35,86.8,87.15,87.65,88.15,88.5,89,89.5,89.85,90.35,90.7,91.05,91.6,91.95,92.3,92.85],
                label: "HIDE!lower",
                borderColor: "transparent",
                backgroundColor: "transparent",
                pointRadius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 5,
                borderWidth: 1,
                fill: false
            }
        ]
    },

    //configuration options
    options: {
        animation: true,
        aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
        interaction: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: 'index',
            axis: 'x'
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                label: "time",
                grid: {
                    display: true
                },

            },
            y: {
                label: "meassure",
                grid: {
                    display: true
                },
                stacked: false,
                beginAtZero: false,
                position: "right",
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(val, index) {
                        return parseInt(val) + ' cm';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                position: 'nearest',
                caretSize: 7,
                caretPadding: 10,
                filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    if(tooltipItem.dataset.label.includes('HIDE!')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                    font: {
                        size: 14,
                        family: 'Inter, "sans-serif"'
                    },
                    filter: function(item, chart) {
                        return !item.text.includes('HIDE!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
const orgdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartdata));

//draw chart
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('rainbow').getContext('2d');
    chart = new Chart(ctx, chartdata);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to implement a custom position: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#custom-position-modes

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the custome positioner.

Here is an example on how to implement it:

```
// Define the custom position mode function
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.custom = function(elements, eventPosition) {
  var tooltipWidth = this._chart.tooltip._view.width;
  var chartArea = this._chart.chartArea;
  var xPosition = eventPosition.x;
  var yPosition = eventPosition.y;
  
  // Check if the hovered element belongs to the second dataset
  if (elements[0]._datasetIndex === 1) {
    // If yes, set the x position to be the center of the chart
    xPosition = chartArea.left + chartArea.width / 2;
  }
  
  return {
    x: xPosition - tooltipWidth / 2,
    y: yPosition
  };
};

var chartdata = {
 = {
  type: 'line',
  ...
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      position: 'custom'
    }
  }
};
```

You can find more help in [ChartJS documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#custom-position-modes)

Comment: I'll give you the bounty for sure, since your answer is the most accurate one. But would you care to elaborate using the same jsfiddle code? https://jsfiddle.net/sp4c39fe/

Answer (score 0):

I think setting up `plugins.tooltip.position` to `average` is enough to avoid positioning the tooltip.

*[reference](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes)*

Comment: That doesn't work, because it will look for the average of all the values in the datasets (including the median points, and the stripe points).